# Create a hook function

Tags: hooks

I want to create a hook function so that other modules implement it, any pointers to how it is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't create a hook, in the same way Drupal core doesn't create `hook_nodeapi()`, or `hook_hook_info()`. You write code that uses (invokes) the implementation of a hook done in other modules. The modules that want to interact/integrate with yours will implement that hook, and your module will use `module_invoke()`, `module_invoke_all()`, or `drupal_alter()` to invoke those hooks.

The correct phrase is not *creating a hook*, but *defining a hook*, which is essentially documenting that your module invokes a specific hook.

Answer (score 7):

> Essentially there are 2 things needed to create your own hook(s).
>
> - Create your own function that calls `module_invoke_all('WHAT_YOU_WANT_YOUR_HOOK_TO_BE_CALLED');`
> - Create your new module and a function called `YOURMODULE_WHAT_YOU_WANT_YOUR_HOOK_TO_BE_CALLED()`
>
> That is ALL it actually takes to implement your own hooks in a Drupal module. The great thing here is the flexibility that it provides for you to do anything, AND allow other developers to easily extend your work. The major consideration I can see here is naming your hook. You should obviously try to choose something unique to your module, that a
>   core or another contributed module wont be using.